# How do you stop Jetty altering the HTTP Expires header when using response.addCookie?

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, cookies, jetty

It turns out in Jetty, when you attach a cookie, it not only adds a cookie to the HTTP response header, it also alters the value of the Expires HTTP header!

```
((HttpServletResponse)response).addCookie(cookie);
```

I need Jetty to stop screwing around with the correct/proper expiry settings.

On a side note, Is there a particular/good reason for it to be behaving like this? My guess is that Jetty is assuming that if a cookie has been set, the content is always dynamic, and hence should be set to *expired* so that it is not cached.

**Update:** Testing this using *Jetty 8.1.8.v20121106*

Comment: what if you add cookie first, then set Expires. will jetty still mess around with it?

Comment: What version of Jetty are you using?

Comment: Doh! I meant to add the jetty version, but forgot, im using what was latest as of last month, (Jetty 8.1.8.v20121106). I should check if there is a newer release (Cant wait for 9 to come out)

Comment: The [Eclipse website](http://download.eclipse.org/jetty/) lists version 9 being stable.

Comment: It appears you _can't__ re-adjust the headers after the cookie has been added.

Comment: It appears 9 has just become stable as of a few days ago. I cant see an announcement about it though. cf http://download.eclipse.org/jetty/

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Just took a walk through the Jetty 8 codebase.
Here are the situations in the codebase where Expires (as a HTTP Response header) is forced to a value, or removed if present.

- Any HTTP 206 response (forced removal, per RFC2616 spec)
- Use of org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.MovedContextHandler (forced if unset)
- During Form Authentication, if the need to respond with an error, via Dispatch handling (forced removal)
- During a Form Authentication challenge response (forced removal)

That's it for Expires as a HTTP Response Header.

However, since you pointed this out as a part of [`.addCookie()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/servlet/http/HttpServletResponse.html#addCookie%28javax.servlet.http.Cookie%29), I'd like to point out that there is also a Cookie spec Expires header, as part of the Cookie value string, found in the Set-Cookie logic on a response.

This will force the Cookie Expires header if the [`Cookie.setMaxAge()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/servlet/http/Cookie.html#setMaxAge%28int%29) value is 0 or greater.  This is done to work around various browser bugs that do not honor `Max-Age=` until `Expires=` is also provided on the Cookie value.

Default behavior of [Cookie](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/servlet/http/Cookie.html):

- `Cookie.setMaxAge(-1);` will disable both `Max-Age=` and `Expires=`
- `Cookie.setMaxAge(0);` will result in `Expires=00:00:00 UTC on 1 January 1970` (start of unix epoch)
- `Cookie.setMaxAge(60000);` will result in a `Expires=` 1 minute in the future.

Version 1 Cookie behavior (aka [`Cookie.setVersion(1)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/servlet/http/Cookie.html#setVersion%28int%29)):

- `Cookie.setMaxAge(-1);` will disable both `Max-Age=` and `Expires=`
- `Cookie.setMaxAge(0);` will result in `Max-Age=0` and `Expires=00:00:00 UTC on 1 January 1970` (start of unix epoch)
- `Cookie.setMaxAge(60000);` will result in `Max-Age=60000` and a `Expires=` 1 minute in the future.

Comment: Awesome! I assumed there would be some quirk that caused this behavior to be built in. Wish I could upvote you more (:

Comment: Isn't it in seconds? ie 60000 would be 1000 minutes rather than 1 minute?